# Java using if statement, for loop and method call

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, methods

In main, create a for loop that will ask for the numeric grade and uses the getLetterGrade method to print out the letter grade, until the user enters a -1. so practically i have to ask the user to enter the grade between 0 and 100 and it will look in the method and print the appropriate grade? correct??? so here's the code

```
System.out.println("Please enter you grade total: ");
Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
studentGrade = Keyboard.nextInt();


for(studentGrade = 0; studentGrade < 1; ++studentGrade){
    System.out.print(getLetterGrade);
```

Create a method called getLetterGrade. The getLetterGrade method takes a grade between 0-100 and then prints out the corresponding letter grade.  The grade ranges are A: 100-90  B: 80-89 C: 70-79, D: 60-69, F: 0-59. In main, create a for loop that will ask for the numeric grade and uses the getLetterGrade method to print out the letter grade, until the user enters a -1."

Here's my code: I wrote using if,else if condition. what i don't understand is that do i have to write the condition in main or the method. Usually i dont have a problem with coding but this thing has me puzzled. I though about using case but if, else if conditions seems alot more straight forward.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class getLetterGrade {

public static void getLetterGrade(String getLetterGrade){


int studentGrade = 0;

    if(studentGrade >= 90) getLetterGrade("A");
    else if(studentGrade >= 80) getLetterGrade("B");
    else if(studentGrade >= 70) getLetterGrade("C");
    else if(studentGrade >= 60) getLetterGrade("D");
    else if(studentGrade >= 0) getLetterGrade("F");
    else 
        System.out.println("you have entered incorrect integer");

int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    System.out.print(studentGrade + " ");
}

System.out.println();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int studentGrade = 0;
    getLetterGrade("A");
    getLetterGrade("B");
    getLetterGrade("C");
    getLetterGrade("D");
    getLetterGrade("F");

    System.out.println("Please enter you grade total: ");
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    studentGrade = Keyboard.nextInt();


    for(studentGrade = 0; studentGrade < 1; ++studentGrade){
        System.out.print(studentGrade);
    }
}




}
```

i know i have to print getLetterGrade but when i try to print getLetterGrade it throws errors, i dont get it.....

thanks for any and all help!!

Comment: looks to me like your getting stackoverflow error because your getLetterGrade is recursing infinitely

Comment: In main, create a for loop that will ask for the numeric grade and uses the getLetterGrade method to print out the letter grade, until the user enters a -1. so practically i have to ask the user to enter the grade between 0 and 100 and it will look in the method and print the appropriate grade? correct??? so here's the code System.out.println("Please enter you grade total: ");
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    studentGrade = Keyboard.nextInt();


    for(studentGrade = 0; studentGrade < 1; ++studentGrade){
        System.out.print(studentGrade);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getLetterGrade method is recursive. In the method, you set studentGrade=0, so the method calls getLetter("A"). This repeats, which results in a stackoverflow error.

I think this is what you want instead:

```
public static void getLetterGrade (int studentGrade) {
    if (studentGrade >= 90) System.out.println("A");
    else if (studentGrade >= 80) System.out.println("B");
    else if (studentGrade >= 70) System.out.println("C");
    else if (studentGrade >= 60) System.out.println("D");
    else if (studentGrade >= 0) System.out.println("F");
    else System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect integer.");
}
```

In your main method, I think this is what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int studentGrade = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (studentGrade != -1) {
        getLetterGrade(studentGrade);
        studentGrade = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
}
```

In the main method, you can't use a for loop because you don't know in advance how many times the user wants to input. The while loop, on the other hand, checks that the input is not -1 and then prints out the grade for each iteration.

You might need to see a tutorial about for loops though. In a for loop, the variable is just an index. It doesn't have the value of whatever it is you assign to it previously.

Answer (score 0):

try this .

```
package com.health;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

```
public static void getLetterGrade(int studentGrade) {

    // int studentGrade = 0;

    if (studentGrade >= 90)
        System.out.println("A");
    else if (studentGrade >= 80)
        System.out.println("B");
    else if (studentGrade >= 70)
        System.out.println("C");
    else if (studentGrade >= 60)
        System.out.println("D");
    else if (studentGrade >= 0)
        System.out.println("E");
    else
        System.out.println("you have entered incorrect integer");

    // int i = 0;
    //
    // for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    // System.out.print(studentGrade + " ");
    // }
    //
    // System.out.println();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int studentGrade = 0;
    // getLetterGrade("A");
    // getLetterGrade("B");
    // getLetterGrade("C");
    // getLetterGrade("D");
    // getLetterGrade("F");

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Please enter you grade total: ");
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        studentGrade = Keyboard.nextInt();

        if (studentGrade == -1) {
            break;
        } else {
            getLetterGrade(studentGrade);
        }

    }

    // for (studentGrade = 0; studentGrade < 1; ++studentGrade) {
    // System.out.print(studentGrade);
    // }
}
```

}

Comment: @JavaCoder There's no way you can use a for loop because you don't know in advance how many times the user wants to input.

Comment: @mmKing Thank you, exactly what I thought. I have to talk to someone tomorrow and figure it out. It just didnt make any sense but i thought i was wrong.

Comment: it is i loop ,if you type '-1' it will stop .